# Estimating Required Time To Complete Weka SMOTE

Tags: weka

I have a dataset where there are two classes, i.e. `yes` and `no`. There are `36972` `no` instances and `243650` `yes` instances. I am trying to increase the number of `no` instances using SMOTE in WEKA.

It is going on for more than three hours but still showing that its in progress. I have viewed the original paper of Chawla but is unable to figure out the estimated run-time of SMOTE for any number of synthetic instances to be created.

Is there any way to estimate run-time of SMOTE with respect to the number of synthetic instances to be created?

Comment: Hi, I know it has been a while since this was asked, but did it finish processing in the end? I am applying SMOTE to a dataset with a total 150,000 instances and it has been processing for a significant amount of time.

Comment: Yes it finished in the end. I switched to a computer of higher configurations to get the results faster. But later I had seen that it worked on a regular computer too but took way more time. I didn't tracked the exact amount of time it took, so unfortunately I can't comment about any estimates.